# Go lang, don't understand what this code does

Tags: go, time

I am noob in golang, but I would like to change a source code that writes data into database every minute to every second. I have trobles to find what Tick does in the code. The config.SampleRate is integer = 1, which means every minute = every 60 seconds

What this tick is all about and the end part of it: <-tick, combined with counter i?

```
i := 0

tick := time.Tick(time.Duration(1000/config.Samplerate) * time.Millisecond)

for {
    // Restart the accumulator loop every 60 seconds.
    if i > (60*config.Samplerate - 1) {
        i = 0
        //some code here
    }

    //some code there

    }
    <-tick
    i++
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tick` is a channel in Go. If you look at the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Tick), `tick` should send something to the channel once each time interval, which is specified by `time.Duration(1000/config.Samplerate) * time.Millisecond` in your code. `<-tick` just waits for that time interval to pass.

`i` keeps track of how many seconds pass, so every time it ticks, you add one to `i`. The if statement checks when one minute passes.

So, the code inside the if statement fires every 60 seconds, while the code right under the if block fires every second.

Comment: So, if I understand the code is wrong, because if I change Samplerate to 10, then it will be ticking at 100ms and the code will execute evey 6s and 100ms respectively?